# Why are parentheses required for array indexing in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In (postgres) SQL, this is valid syntax,

```
select (array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])[1];
```

but not:

```
select array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]][1];
```

... which is a little surprising to me. What's going on here?

Comment: Strange, `select array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]::int[][1];` returns the full array. Which also seems like unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a parser issue. PostgreSQL uses [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) parser - additional parenthesis are required as protection against parsing collisions. The query processing is in stages: parsing, analyse, planning and execution. There are not enough information in parsing time to protect bison against possible collision and then some syntaxes are not disallowed.

Because a arrays was proprietary PostgreSQL feature (very successful) and syntax was not described by ANSI, a developers preferred some compromise design like good enough for users and doesn't require too complex code. A focus of PostgreSQL is in SQL and not in arrays processing. The Bison is very good mature tool, but sometimes due speed requirements some syntaxes are difficult or impossible.

```
select array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]::int[][1]
```

There is not any magic if you know a fact, so limits in arrays types definition are syntactic sugar only. `int[]`,`int[1]`,`int[] [100]`is just `int[]`. Then `array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]::int[][1]` is same like `array[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]::int[]` .. take a numeric array and cast it to integer array.

Comment: "*Because a arrays are proprietary PostgreSQL feature*" that's not true. Arrays **are** defined by the SQL standard. And e.g. `foo[1]` or `array[1,2,3,]` are both valid standard SQL. The standard however does only defines one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thank you for fix, I didn't know it. I though so only sets are supported without special syntax (I corrected the text).